# Where do I find a list of all possible input filters for Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter

Tags: php, validation, oop, zend-framework2

Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter creates inputs with the createInput() method of Zend\InputFilter\Factory. But I was digging through the code and could not find where the actual input filter key value pairs are defined. For example:

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
    'name' => 'id',
    'required' => true,
    'filters' => array(
        array('name' => 'Int'),
    ), ...
```

'Int' is a filter. Where is that defined in the zf2 library so I can see what other possible filters there are. I know the docs have info on this, but I'd like to know where it is defined in the actual library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find it in the class **Zend\Filter\FilterPluginManager**.

The path of the file is **your_project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Filter**

In this directory you'll also find all the filter's classes (like the **Int** one).

Comment: Well now I'm confused. In vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Filter I see Int.php, but there's no String.php? There's StringLength and StringTrim- is there a reason why there is no filter to just check if its a string or not?

Comment: I think you're confused between [filters](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.filter.set.html) and [validators](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.validator.set.html). The filters, like **int**, are used to apply changes to the input data, while validators check if they're valid against some criteria. The **int** you're using is a filter which converts the input data to an integer.